# Taking scheduled or command line snapshot with Netbeans Java profiler

Tags: java, netbeans

I was wondering if it is possible to either schedule memory snapshots using Netbean's java (memory) profiler or at the very least call a profiler that is attached to a running process through command prompt to perform a snapshot.

Reason being, I have a very long running process (talking hours) and I would like to be able to automatically schedule a snapshot every 30 minutes.

Is this possible through Netbean's profiler?